# Access New Excel Feature "Insert Picture Into Cell" With Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, image

I am trying to insert a picture inside a specific cell. This is a new excel feature and I was wondering if there was a way to access it via Python.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZ87gcncKZM

While things like Xlsxwriter allow me to insert a picture in Excel, there are not contained within a specific cell. Wondering if a new tool was available to do so.

Comment: This does not seem like a question. Please read the how to ask section of stackoverflow and make sure to come back once you have a nice programming question with a reproducible example

Comment: This does not seem like a question. Please read the how to ask section of stackoverflow and make sure to come back once you have a nice programming question with a reproducible example